# How to make an item of a GtkComboBox disabled/unclickable

Tags: c, gtk

I've been trying to get some items of a combobox to be disabled. The best I can get is to make the text color grey and add a strikethrough by adding attributes to the combo, but I can still select the "disabled" items and the hover highlight is still blue as in the other, active items.

The ideal behavior would be similar to a separator, but instead of a large line, the text of the item would be rendered.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't include those items in the list.  That or write your own list handling code.

Comment: @jwdonahue I need them on the list to communicate to the user that they exist, but are not available for selection at that moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution could be to use the GtkCellRenderer and set the "sensitive" property with gtk_cell_layout_set_cell_data_func accordingly, which

> > Sets the GtkCellLayoutDataFunc to use for cell_layout .
> >     This function is used instead of the standard attributes mapping for setting the column value, and should set the value of cell_layout ’s cell renderer(s) as appropriate.

see

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellLayout.html#gtk-cell-layout-set-cell-data-func

**Example**

```
#include <glib/gi18n.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static GtkTreeModel *combo_model(void) {
    const gchar *labels[] = {
            N_("Show Bookmarks"),
            N_("Edit Bookmarks"),
            N_("Previous Item"),
            N_("Next Item"),
    };

    GtkListStore *store = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    for (gint i = 0; i < G_N_ELEMENTS(labels); i++) {
        gtk_list_store_append(store, &iter);
        gtk_list_store_set(store, &iter, 0, labels[i], -1);
    }

    return GTK_TREE_MODEL(store);
}

static void set_sensitive(GtkCellLayout *cell_layout,
              GtkCellRenderer *cell,
              GtkTreeModel *tree_model,
              GtkTreeIter *iter,
              gpointer data) {
    gchar *text;
    gtk_tree_model_get (tree_model, iter, 0, &text, -1);
    gboolean sensitive = g_strcmp0(N_("Previous Item"), text) != 0;
    g_free (text);
    g_object_set(cell, "sensitive", sensitive, NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Disabled Item Demo");
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroyed), &window);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 32);

    GtkTreeModel *model = combo_model();
    GtkWidget *combo = gtk_combo_box_new_with_model(model);
    g_object_unref(model);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), combo);

    GtkCellRenderer *renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
    gtk_cell_layout_pack_start(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(combo), renderer, TRUE);
    gtk_cell_layout_set_attributes(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(combo), renderer, "text", 0, NULL);
    gtk_cell_layout_set_cell_data_func(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(combo), renderer, set_sensitive, NULL, NULL);
    gtk_combo_box_set_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo), 0);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

**Demo**

When you run the above sample code, it looks similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Please, how i can do that in Python?